# How to reduce the probability density function of binary normal distribution to the form of textbook

Tags: simplifying-expressions, probability-or-statistics, distributions

The probability density function of binary normal distribution in textbooks is in the following form:

[image]

```
Refine[PDF[
  MultinormalDistribution[{μ1, μ2}, {{σ1^2, ρ*\
σ1*σ2}, {ρ*σ1*σ2, σ2^2}}], {x,
    y}], σ1 > 0 && σ2 > 0 && ρ > 0]
(-(1/(2 (1 - ρ^2) )) ((x - μ1)^2/ (σ1^2)  - (
     2 ρ (x - μ1) (y - μ2))/( σ1 σ2) + (y \
- μ2)^2/ (σ2^2) ) // Expand)

(1/2 (-(((x - μ1) (μ1 σ2 - μ2 ρ σ1 - \
σ2 x + ρ σ1 y))/((ρ^2 - 
         1) σ1^2 σ2)) - ((y - μ2) (-(μ1 ρ \
σ2) + μ2 σ1 + ρ σ2 x + σ1 \
(-y)))/((ρ^2 - 1) σ1 σ2^2)) // Expand)
```

Although the expansion form of `PDF[MultinormalDistribution[{μ1, μ2}, {{σ1^2, ρ*
σ1*σ2}, {ρ*σ1*σ2, σ2^2}}], {x, y}]` is consistent with the textbook, I still want to reduce it to the following output form and keep it unchanged:

```
1/(2 π*σ1*σ2*(1 - ρ^2)^(1/2))*
 E^(-(1/(2 (1 - ρ^2))) ((x - μ1)^2/(σ1^2) - (2 ρ \
(x - μ1) (y - μ2))/(σ1 σ2) + (y - μ2)^2/(\
σ2^2)))
```

$$ \frac{1}{2\pi\sigma1\sigma2\sqrt{(1-\rho^{2})}} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^{2})}(\frac{(x-\mu1)^{2}}{\sigma1^{2}}-\frac{2\rho(x-\mu1)(y-\mu2)}{\sigma1\sigma2}+\frac{(y-\mu2)^{2}}{\sigma2^{2}})} $$

**What should I do?**

Comment: Use [`BinormalDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinormalDistribution.html), i.e., `PDF[BinormalDistribution[{μ1, μ2}, {σ1, σ2}, ρ], {x, y}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you very much, but how to reduce the above content to the required output format through `Simplify` and `Collect` functions, etc.

Comment: A starting point: `Simplify[MapAll[Factor, PDF[MultinormalDistribution[{μ1, μ2}, {{σ1^2, ρ*σ1*σ2}, {ρ*σ1*σ2, σ2^2}}], {x, y}]], σ1 > 0 && σ2 > 0 && ρ > 0] /. Power[p_, q_] :> Power[p, Normal[Simplify[Series[Numerator[q], {y, μ2, 2}]]]/Denominator[q]]`.